# How to inherit a template in django if some condition is met?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to achieve the following in django, conceptually is good, but, django template language does not allow this because the "extends" templatetag must be the in the first line.

```
{% if some condition %}
    {% extends "parent_template.html "%}
{% else %} 
    {% extends "another_parent_template.html "%}
{% endif %}
```

Any workaround for this?, 90% of the inherited and uniherited themplate remains the same, it is worthless to have two different templates for this.

Comment: can you do `{%extends parent_passed_in_variable%}` ? I dont know if it would accept that or not ... just an idea though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a workaround for this.   But the bigger answer is that you should consider designing your template differently.

If it's true that 90% of the content comes from `parent_template.html` then extending that template shouldn't be conditional.  Do it all of the time.  If not, then consider designing like this:

- Template A checks `some_condition`.  If true:

  - A includes template `B_some_condition`, which extends from `parent_template.html`.
- If false,

  - A include template `B_else`, which doesn't extend anything.

In this way, instead of putting the conditional in the child template, and making the "extends" conditional, you put the conditional in whatever is using that template (A).